# solving the error spring boot java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type without @Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

after i get an answer on my question [spring boot modeling MySQL native query result with a class without creating a table entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384122/spring-boot-modeling-mysql-native-query-result-with-a-class-without-creating-a-t) i am following the answer witch consist of this guide here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions but i get stuck with the error `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restBesoinsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'statistics'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticsRepositor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class fr.solinum.management.model.Statistic`
i tried all the solution in the questions related to `Not a managed type` except adding `@Entity` to the model class since the guide state that

> The JPA specification allows us to customize results in an object-oriented fashion. Therefore, we can use a JPQL constructor expression to set the result:
> @Query("SELECT new com.baeldung.aggregation.model.custom.CommentCount(c.year, COUNT(c.year)) "
> +"FROM Comment AS c GROUP BY c.year ORDER BY c.year DESC")
> List countTotalCommentsByYearClass();
> This binds the output of the SELECT statement to a POJO. **The class specified needs to have a constructor that matches the projected attributes exactly, but it's not required to be annotated with @Entity.**

and that is exactly what i want to achieve.

here is my Controller , Model and Repository

RestBesoinsController:

```
@RestController
public class RestBesoinsController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestBesoinsController.class);

    @Autowired
    private StatisticsRepositor statistics;

    @GetMapping("/api/besoins")
    public List<Besoin> getBesoins() {
        logger.info("APPEL RestBesoinsController");
        List<Besoin> Besoins = besoinService.findAll();
        return Besoins;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/besoins/{term}")
    public List<Besoin> getBesoinsByFilter(@PathVariable String term) {
        logger.info("APPEL RestBesoinsController");
        List<Besoin> besoins = besoinService.findByTitre(term);
        besoins = besoins.stream().filter(a -> a.getEtatBesoin().equals(EtatBesoin.GAGNE)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return besoins;
    }

    @GetMapping("/plot")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Statistic> plot(@RequestParam("date") int year) {
        List<Statistic> resp = statistics.getStatistic(year);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Statistic Model in package `fr.solinum.management.model` note that this package have many models and they work fine

```
public class Statistic {
    
    private String state;
    private Long number;
    
    public Statistic(String state,Long number) {
        this.state = state;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
}
```

finally the repository is in `fr.solinum.management.repository`

```
@Repository
public interface StatisticsRepositor extends JpaRepository<Statistic, Integer>{
    @Query("SELECT new fr.solinum.management.model.Statistic(b.etat_besoin,COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)) FROM besoin AS b WHERE YEAR(b.date_creation)=:year GROUP BY b.etat_besoin")
    List<Statistic> getStatistic(@Param("year") int year);
}
```

**is there a way to continue this guide without using `@Entity`? what i am missing or what i should change?**

Comment: For Spring to create an object, the object needs to have a default constructor. It will create the object without any parameters and then fill them in with the appropriate `set` methods.

Comment: sorry , it does not work